# DOM issue after loading more with Ajax - SilverStripe

Tags: jquery, ajax, silverstripe

I am working on a page using SilverStripe that contains load more Ajax. This is the html structure

```
<div id="pagination"...>
    // items goes here
</div>
<div id="loadmore"...>
    // load more button
</div>
```

Whenever there is an Ajax call the `#pagination` div empties itself and appends the response data. Since the load more button needs to be update the link, I included it in the response data (render with template).

```
success: function(data) {
    loadmore.remove();
    container.empty();
    container.append(data);
}
```

This, however, causes a problem that the load more div is nested inside the `pagination` div after Ajax.

Any idea how can I overcome this?

Comment: UPDATE:

I finally got it worked though the solution is not really professional. I added a comment in the html and split the response by that comment. 

The pagination div appends the first split string and the big div containing both pagination and loadmore will append the second split string.

Though I really hope for better solutions

Comment: You can write an answer with your solution and self-accept after some time.

Comment: Just create a template that only contains "pagination" and return that via AJAX? In JS you can then just do: `$("#pagination").replaceWith($(data));`

Comment: @bummzack The thing is that when ajax load, the loadmore div also needs to be updated. If I do replaceWith I think it is similar to empty() then append(), and the loadmore div will be nested in pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your template to look like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="pagination"...>
        // items goes here
    </div>
    <div id="loadmore"...>
        // load more button
    </div>
</div>
```

Then do:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#wrapper").replaceWith($(data));
}
```

If you don't want to add additional DOM nodes, you can rewrite your callback handler to look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var content = $(data);
    $("#pagination").replaceWith(content.filter("#pagination"));
    $("#loadmore").replaceWith(content.filter("#loadmore"));
}
```